# error 42601 syntax error at or near

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm using a c# application to load a postgresql table with appropriate data. Here is the code:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;UserId=postgres;Password=***** ;Database=postgres;");
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
try {
  command.CommandText = "insert into projets (ID, Title, Path, Description, DateCreated) values('" + pro.ID + "','" + pro.Title + "','" + pro.Path + "', '' ,'" + pro.DateCreated + "')";
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch {
  throw;
}
conn.Close();
```

However, when executing the code, i keep getting the same error:

```
error 42601 syntax error at or near...
```

I didnt find how to escape the apostroph.

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting into `projets` and not `projects`?

Comment: error at or near *what*?

Comment: In addition to what @Brandon has said, i would recommend using [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) which would resolve the issue of escaping strings altogether and would help to prevent SQL Injection attacks at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write your command using a parametrized query

```
command.CommandText = "insert into projets (ID, Title, Path, Description, DateCreated) " + 
                     "values(@id, @title, @path, '', @dt);";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pro.ID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pro.Title);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", pro.PAth)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", pro.DateCreated);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this way, if one of your strings values contain a single quote, you leave the job to correctly parse your values to the framework code and you avoid problems with [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)